# Warns: Option has been declared with a 'no' prefix

Tags: javascript, angular, ts-jest

I updated angular to ver.14.
When I use ng test I've got warns

```
Warning: 'no-cache' option has been declared with a 'no' prefix in the schema.Please file an issue with the author of this package.
Warning: 'noStackTrace' option has been declared with a 'no' prefix in the schema.Please file an issue with the author of this package.
```

How I can fix it?
p.s. I use jest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular 14, `yargs` was introduced to parse CLI arguments (see [#22778](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/22778)).

`yargs` handles arguments prefixed with "no" differently, so there was a regression in the parsing behavior (see [#23397](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23397)). With [#23405](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/23405), a temporary fix was introduced, which results in the warning you see.

You can either use the inverted option flag or wait until the Angular team creates a more permanent fix.

Comment: Im not using noStackTrace at all, and the only no-cache I found (in my angular.json architect test section) I inverted to `cache: true`yet I still get the warnings.  WI dont see noStackTrace anywhere in node_modules either. Any idea where they are?